# How to access non member functions that are in a seperate file (.cpp) than main

Tags: c++, function, static, static-methods

So I am working on my first multiple file, non-toy, c++ project. I have a class that represents a multi-spectral image and all the information that goes along with it.

My problem is how to design the part of the program that loads and object of this class with a file from disk!

I don't think I need a class for this. Would switching to a functional approach be better for the file loading. This way I can have just a source file (.cpp) that has functions I can call while passing in pointers to the relevant objects that will be updated by the file accessed by the function.

I don't think static functions are what I want to use? As I understand it they(static functions) are for accessing static variables within a class, aren't they?

If I go the functional route, from `main()`, how do I access these functions? I assume I would include the functions .cpp file at the beginning of the `main()` containing file. From there how do I call the functions. Do i just use the function name or do I have to pre-pend something similar to what you have to pre-pend when including a class and then calling its methods.

Here is some example code of what I have tried and the errors I get.

OpenMultiSpec.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

void test(){
    std::cout << "Test function accessed successfully" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(){

    test();

    return 1;
}
```

The error says " 'test' was not declared in this scope "

Comment: So, in eclipse, it does not seem like I have to "include" the function() .cpp file in the file that has main() but, how do I access the functions?

Comment: Usually, you put their declaration in a header and include it in the code that needs to call the functions.

Comment: But doesn't that make it a class? Then I have to instantiate objects to use these functions!

Comment: You can have a non-class function declared in a header and then implemented in a cpp file. The aspect of something being part of a class or not has nothing to do with where you put it in header or code files.

Comment: If you define your function or variables as global, then you can access these functions anywhere within the .cpp file without making a reference to any class. Now if you want to access these global functions from another .cpp file then you have to create header files for your .cpp file that contains the global functions. And then add the header file to the .cpp file where you are trying to call these global functions. Because the compiler will look for the definition of these global functions in you main and if it cannot locate it, then it will search for it on the header files.

Comment: My first comment has been removed for some reason, but it was telling you that whether you have classes or functions has absolutely nothing to do with whether you use header files or not. The concepts are completely unrelated. That was supposed to hint to you that you are approaching this problem from the wrong side.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMultiSpec.h

```
void test();
```

main.cpp

```
#include "OpenMultiSpec.h"
int main(){

    test();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: So I only want to have one file, not two. Should I "inline" the functions in the .h file?

Comment: @aaronburns No. You should use C++ the way it was designed to and have OpenMultiSpec.h with function prototypes and OpenMultiSpec.cpp with function code. Inlining functions in header files increases compilation times.

Comment: @aaronburns for every .cpp you should have a .h containing the function prototypes (and class interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

If they're in two separate files, and in your case, one being a header, use

```
#include "OpenMultiSpec.h"
```

If you decide to only use one file (as your comment says above), you won't need #include for your header file. Just place your function declaration anywhere before you call it.

```
#include <iostream>
void test() {
     std::cout << "Test function accessed successfully" << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    test();

    return 1;
}
```